# How do you compute the run time for the naive solution for Matrix Chain Multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication, catalan

I'm working on Matrix Chain Multiplication. And the naive solution is equivalent to the Catalan number of the problem.

This is what it says in the solution. That the naive solution ends up working out to be O(2^n) by reducing the parenthesizing problem to a binary tree. Then computing all the binary trees for a given input.

I just don't understand how you go from parenthesizing a matrix chain multiplication to a binary tree. I would have never figured that out myself.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying and this is an interesting problem. According to this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/ it says you can take the dimensions of each matrix and use that to determine how many operations each matrix multiplication will cost.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. The binary tree method for run time analysis seems much more elegant. I'm just a bit shocked because I would have never thought of doing that and I feel that I'm lacking some understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The binary expression tree isn't a new concept. We are working with binary operations and thereby recall that we can convert the parenthesizing to a binary expression tree. Then ask ourselves, how many binary expression trees exist?

It might be intresting to do run time analysis on a problem where it's K-ary expression tree.